# Bootstrap menu height issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I overwritten part of the bootstrap css to get my height of the navbar and colors. Active menu item is on below image. There is one pixel size difference and background color shows up at the bottom.
Does anybody know how to fix it ? My scss code below

[image: Bootstrap active]

```
$mainColor: #006600;
$navbarActive: yellowgreen;
$navbarDefault: white;
$navbarHooveer: yellowgreen;

body { padding-top: 13px; }

@media (min-width: 1040px) {
    .container{
    max-width: 1040px;
    }
}

.container-fluid {
    max-width: 1040px;
}

.navbar { min-height: 35px; }
.navbar .navbar-brand{ padding: 0px 0px;font-size: 16px; line-height:     35px; height: 35px; }
.navbar .navbar-nav { margin-left: 120px;}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {  padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 20px; height: 35px;}
.navbar .navbar-toggle {  margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 0px; }
.navbar .navbar-form { margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 0px; }
.navbar-nav > li > a { height: 35px; padding-top: 8px !important;     padding-bottom: 5px !important; }

.btn-success, .btn-success:hover, .btn-success:active, .btn-success:visited {
    background-color: $mainColor !important;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: $mainColor;
    border-color: $mainColor;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: $navbarDefault;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: $navbarDefault;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
color: $navbarDefault;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: $navbarDefault;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: $navbarHooveer;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: $navbarDefault;
    background-color: $navbarActive;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: $navbarDefault;
    background-color: $navbarActive;
    border-color: $navbarActive;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: $mainColor;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: $mainColor;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: $navbarDefault;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: $navbarDefault;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
    color: $navbarDefault;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
    color: $navbarDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's just a border:

```
.navbar {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

navbar-fixed-top has this style:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```

you can override it by setting **border-width: 0;**